# targeting a specific block with e2fsck to shorten wait

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, ext4, fsck

Recently had a LVM'd CentOS 6.5 install get accidentally cold-shutdown.  On bootup, it says that the home partition need fscking:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home: Block bitmap for group 3072 is not in group.  (block 3335668205)

/dev/mapper/vg_myserver-lv_home: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
```

...but I guess the root partition is OK, since it gives me a shell there.  So we run `e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/mapper/vg_myserver/lv_home` and after saying Yes to various fixes, on Pass 5 it just prints endless numbers to the screen, very fast.  Once in a while it will print them in neat columns, and if these are block numbers, after a couple hours we are still nowhere near the first 2% being done of our 1.2 TB LV.

I read that you can use `cleap_mmp` with `tune2fs`, but upon trying that, it doesn't accept cleap_mmp nor list it among valid options.

My question is, how does everyone deal with a corrupt ext4 fs without weeks of downtime?  Does everyone have this dilemma, or weeks of downtime vs rebuilding your server / lost data?  If so why does anyone use or recommend the use of ext4?  Is there some trick I'm missing that would **let me target the specific block/group it's complaining about**, so we can get on with it and mount the home fs again?

Comment: Did you have write caching enabled on a raid card without a bbu?

Comment: @jordanm, that's a good point.  I'm not sure we do have a BBU on it--it's a lower-end DL380 G5, so probably not.  If write caching is enabled by default, then we probably ended up with this disaster recipe...so that's helpful for future avoidance, but my question still stands, because I'm not the only one, according to Google, that faces running `fsck` for weeks and gives up.  I may be the only one dumb enough to face this on a production server that needs to be going by Monday morning, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `e2fsck -y` to say yes to all questions automatically instead of having to manually say yes a million times.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem of a failed or problematic disk is to restore from backups.  If it is a hardware problem, replace the disk first.

Attempting to rebuild a broken filesystem is an extremely time consumming operation that seldom results in good results.

Comment: It may have been related to a RAID disk (in a RAID5 array, so it should not have affected the data as visible to the OS, IMU) that needed replacing.  It's been replaced and the array has rebuilt itself, but unfortunately, the replacement occurred hours of production data after the last backup.  If the filesystem is broken so easily yet so difficult to fix, do people really rely on it in production?

Comment: I have not had any problems with ext4 filesystems (other than with bad disks).  If you are concerned be sure to keep patched up with the current release of the ext4 software package.

Comment: @Kev From my experience ext3/4 handles the breakage the best. After the fsck you might lose some data but always end up with a usable filesystem. I can't say the same about other popular filesystems such as XFS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `fsck` ended today.  Rebooted and everything worked great!

Comment: This is not an answer and thus should be added to the question.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: It *did* end my dilemma.  I did not have to find a way to shorten `fsck`'s runtime.  Maybe not strictly an answer, but neither is mdpc's.  If someone would like to address the issue of directing `fsck` towards the specific block/group it's complaining about, I'd be happy to upvote their answer.  Otherwise all I was finding on Google was about people having to wait days or weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ext4 feature `uninit_bg` (`man tune2fs`). Using that may reduce `e2fsck` time:

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdx | grep "^Filesystem features:"
```